# Extractive Text Summarization: Weighting sentence location in document

Tags: pandas, nltk, summarization

I am looking at an extractive text summarization problem. Eventually, I want to generate a list of words (not sentences) that seem to be the most important. One of the ideas that I had was to the words that appear early in the document more heavily.

---

I have two dataframes. the first is a set of words with their occurrence counts:

```
words.head()

words   occurrences
0   ''      2
1   11-1    1
2   2nd     1
3   april   1
4   b.
```

And the second is a set of sentences. 0 is the first sentence in the document, 1 is the secont.. etc.

```
sentences.head()

sentences
0   Site Menu expandHave a correction?...
1   This will be a chance for ...
2   The event will include...
3   Further, this...
4   Contact:Share:
```

---

I managed to accomplish my goal like this:

```
weights = []
for value in words.index.values:
    weights.append(((len(sentences) - sentences.index.values) *
    sentences['sentences'].str.contains(words['words'][value])).sum())

weights
[0,
 5,
 5,
 0,
 12,...]

words['occurrences'] *= weights

words.head()
words   occurrences
0   ''      0
1   11-1    5
2   2nd     5
3   april   0
4   b.  12
```

However, this seems sort of sloppy. I know that I can use list comprehension (I thought it would be easier to read on here without it) - but, other than that, does anyone have thoughts on a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: have you checked `Tfidfvectorizer` from sklearn ? It actually does the same thing as you want: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

Comment: Does it? I thought that the use case for term frequency - inverse document frequency was more in line with training a model on many documents.

IE it will ignore words that appear in all of your documents (like 'the') but catch odd words like 'snaggleraptor'

Does it also have the capacity to weight based on position in a document? I didn't see anything in the docs about it but maybe I missed it!